# Core plot : Displaying several graphs in a single page?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

Am trying to use Core Plot to display several graphs in a single page in an iPhone App. Each graph refreshes every few minutes. What is a good way to structure this programmatically? 
I initially thought that I have only two graphs to display in a page and so had two UIViewControllers (each displaying one graph) and added them as subviews to a superview. Now, with having to display nearly 5 or 6 graphs, I doubt if this would be recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding hosting views with separate graphs to a top-level view is certainly the easiest way to do this. If this works in your app without running out of memory or significantly affecting performance, this is the recommended approach.

The alternative is a single hosting view and graph. Since you'll only have one plot area to work with, you'll need to adjust the plot space(s) used in each subgraph so the data for each one appears in the appropriate section of the graph. Use the `visibleRange` to limit the length of the axes to keep them separate. You'll also need to filter the data for each plot so it doesn't go outside the desired area.

Comment: +1 thanks, Eric! I seriously have to applaud the awesome work you folks do on Core Plot! And beyond that, answering users' questions! Oh my! Can't imagine myself being able to do something so intense as this! Kudos to you folks! Let me stick to the straight-forward way for now ; if, as you say, I run into issues, I'll revisit my approach. Thank you.

Comment: +1 Tks Eric.. for awesome work and support (off course, I'm using Core Plot, too)